# how to print a right angle triangle in c++ using single loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops

this is the code that I wrote for printing the pattern using single however it doesn't work can you help me out.

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int line, star = 0, n;
        cin >> n;
        for (line = 1; line <= n; line++)
        {
            if (star < n)
            {
                cout << "*";
                star++;
                continue;
            }
            if (star == line)
            {
                cout << endl;
                star 
            }
        }
        
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: To print a row of 10 stars:- std::cout << std::string(10, '*');

Answer (score 0):

To print the right angle triangle we can use the string and then add some of the part to it to increase the length of string which looks similar to a triangle.

Here is my code:

```
void solve()
{  
   string a = "*";
   string add_to_a= "*";
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   {
       cout<<a<<"\n";
       a+=add_to_a;
   }
}
```

Comment: and what if we have to invert the right angle triangle then the concatenation won't work as you have to decrement In the loop?

Answer (score -2):

//Try this Code to print right angled triangle in c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void printPattern(int n)
{

    // Variable initialization

    int line_no = 1; // Line count
 

    // Loop to print desired pattern

    int curr_star = 0;

    for (int line_no = 1; line_no <= n; )

    {

        // If current star count is less than

        // current line number

        if (curr_star < line_no)

        {

           cout << "* ";

           curr_star++;

           continue;

        }
 

        // Else time to print a new line

        if (curr_star == line_no)

        {

           cout << "\n";

           line_no++;

           curr_star = 0;

        }

    }
}
 
// Driver code

int main()
{

    printPattern(7);

    return 0;
}
```

//Output of the code

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

Comment: Don't  `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. Some kid could find it. [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).